# Bash script to append netstat output to file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

being a big fan of learning the basics before tackling more advanced projects, I ask this question with a sigh and a shake of my head...I like to monitor incoming/outgoing connections in realtime ( netstat -natuec ) but sometimes I get caught up in what I'm doing...So I would like to create a script that would append any **NEW** ip address that shows up from the netstat command to a txt file for review later.  I'm not asking for an easy answer, just a clue as to where I would start.  THANKS!

Comment: My suggestion would be to write a script in your language of choice that taps into /proc/net/tcp since it would be more script friendly than screen scraping netstat.

Comment: Thats new for me, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite bash but perl, but it does what you want, here is the whole script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Socket;
use feature 'say';

sub hex_to_ip {my $i = shift; inet_ntoa( pack( "N", hex( $i ) ) )}
sub addresses {open(my $net,"<","/proc/net/tcp"); my %add;while(<$net>) {my $r = (split " ",$_)[2];$r =~ s/(rem.*|:.*)//; $add{hex_to_ip($r)}++}; return %add};

my %old;
while(1) {
open(my $new_file,">>","/tmp/new_connections.txt");
my %fresh = &addresses;
for my $f(keys %fresh) {
    my $current_time = localtime;
    say $new_file "$f $current_time\n" unless exists $old{$f};
}
close $new_file;
say "!!"; %old = %fresh; sleep 2;
}
```

function to convert hex to ip

```
sub hex_to_ip {my $i = shift; inet_ntoa( pack( "N", hex( $i ) ) )}
```

returns all remote addresses found in "/proc/net/tcp"

```
sub addresses {open(my $net,"<","/proc/net/tcp"); 
   my %add;while(<$net>) {my $r = (split " ",$_)[2];
   $r =~ s/(rem.*|:.*)//; $add{hex_to_ip($r)}++}; return %add
 }
```

opens a file for appending (does not clobber what is in it)

```
open(my $new_file,">>","/tmp/new_connections.txt");
```

runs the entire life of the program

```
while(1)
```

Gets a fresh copy of the current addresses, and if $old does not have them, it writes to the file with a timestamp. (Since $old is not populated on the first try, it will write all the addresses on the first loop) and sleeps for two seconds.

```
 my %fresh = &addresses;
for my $f(keys %fresh) {
    my $current_time = localtime;
    say $new_file "$f $current_time" unless exists $old{$f};
}
say "!!"; %old = %fresh; sleep 2;
```

}

Comment: Yup that does it...I have a lot to learn because that command is chinese to me...thanks!

Comment: I would mark your answer as accepted, as it does exactly what I want, but I was hoping to be pointed in right direction, though I admit that this saved me a lot of time! Thanks salparadise!

Comment: There are no private messages. Maybe try chat once you have sufficient privileges.

Comment: Made an edit to place the opening/writing of the file into the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

1.exec netstat & get the ip address
2.grep ip result.txt
3.if there is no that ip, write this one,otherwise don't.

You can crontab to exec your script.

Comment: I think he wants to find new IP addresses that show up in netstat, he wouldn't know which one he is looking for.

Comment: Yes, I would like to find new ip addresses, but lemme mess with this idea...thanks!

Comment: There you need to loop every ip to grep result.txt to make sure the existence or not, then to decide whether write to result.txt or not.